# bash script using multiple arrays

Tags: bash

I would like to run multiple command inside a for loop that will contain two arrays. In other words, I need to have a nested for loop that will execute the commands with the following process:

1. echo one
2. echo 8df6
3. echo two
4. echo b4c2
5. echo three
6. echo 9fad

   below is some code that tried, but couldn't apply what needed.

```
#!/bin/bash
numbers=(one two three)

numbersid=(8df6 b4c2 9fad)

for m in "${numbers[@]}"
do
    echo "${m}";
for n in "${numbersid[@]}"
do
    echo "${n}" ;
done
done;
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the output for your code, you would notice that having 2 `for` loops inside each other results in running the nested `for` loop every iteration of the first `for` loop.

Therefore, after every `number` you will have all the `numberids` print.

Your goal is to print both the `number` and the `numberid` after each other. So you want to iterate over the length of the `number` array. And then print the `number`, and its `id`.

You can achieve that in the following way.

```
#!/bin/bash
numbers=(one two three)

numbersid=(8df6 b4c2 9fad)

for i in "${!numbers[@]}"
do
    echo "${numbers[i]}";
    echo "${numbersid[i]}";
done;
```

Answer (score 3):

in this case a single loop would suffice:

```
#!/bin/bash
numbers=(one two three)
numbersid=(8df6 b4c2 9fad)

for index in 0 1 2
do      
        echo ${numbers[$index]}
        echo ${numbersid[$index]}
done
```

gives:

```
one
8df6
two
b4c2
three
9fad
```

Note that bash can help you extract the indices of an array:

```
#...............v
for index in "${!numbers[@]}"; do
        echo ${numbers[index]}
        echo ${numbersid[index]}
done
```

Comment: Avoid `seq`; if you are using `bash`, then a C-style `for` loop is simpler and more efficient: `for ((index=0; index < ${#numbers[@]}; index++))`. If you need POSIX compatibility, you can't rely on `seq` being available anyway, so you should use a `while` loop that explicitly manages `index`.